# Weird inkscape shape bug/setting - everything is white

Tags: inkscape

new to this community. I've found this weird Inkscape bug in the latest version 0.92, where the shapes are on the canvas but appear without colour. I have no idea how to fix this. I have tried to reinstall it.

This is what I have:

1. Created a square
2. Tried to set the colour in the fill and stokes tab. Alpha is 100
3. Just get a blank box

This is from the new install and blank canvas. huhh?

Help?
[image]

Comment: It's not a bug. The opacity is set to 0%. That means it's fully transparent. Move the slider to 100%. Alpha in the colour is not the same as opacity. They are two different attributes.

Comment: Thanks Bill, thats a big win for me. I thought the two were the same.